# Crystal Report- How can i count records of users from different related tables?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am using Crystal Report2008.I have user table, this table is linked with other table such as devises, photos, videos, emails, notes, texts by its Uid and users have record in all different tables. I want a report which shows that how many record each user has in each table.

I am also getting this error: "More than one data source or a stored procedure has been used in this report. please make sure that no SQL Expression is added an no server-side group-by is performed."

Thank You

Comment: Are your tables linked properly to each other?

Answer (score 0):

With the tables linked, it is not possible to get an accurate count. Your joins will affect how many records are returned.

You need to write one report for each table. If there's a need to see the numbers all on one page, you could write a subreport for each table then put the subreports all together on one page.